# Adding multiple strings of text to a marquee separated by a paragraph

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, marquee

I have a user control which creates an animation of scrolling text and on my main window I call it like this:

```
xmlns:mar="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4.AppPages"
<mar:Feed Background="DarkGray" FontSize="12" MarqueeTimeInSeconds="8" 
          Foreground="Gray" Margin="7,383,711,6" MarqueeContent="Live Feed" 
          MarqueeType="TopToBottom"></mar:Feed>
```

The code for the user control looks like this:

```
    MarqueeType _marqueeType;

    public MarqueeType MarqueeType
    {
        get { return _marqueeType; }
        set { _marqueeType = value; }
    }       

    public String MarqueeContent
    {
        set { tbmarquee.Text = value; }
    }

    private double _marqueeTimeInSeconds;

    public double MarqueeTimeInSeconds
    {
        get { return _marqueeTimeInSeconds; }
        set { _marqueeTimeInSeconds = value; }
    }

    public Feed()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        canMain.Height = this.Height;
        canMain.Width = this.Width;
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Feed_Loaded);
    }

    void Feed_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StartMarqueeing(_marqueeType);
    }

    public void StartMarqueeing(MarqueeType marqueeType)
    {
            TopToBottomMarquee();
    }

    private void TopToBottomMarquee()
    {
        double width = canMain.ActualWidth - tbmarquee.ActualWidth;
        tbmarquee.Margin = new Thickness(width / 2, 0, 0, 0);
        DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        doubleAnimation.From = -tbmarquee.ActualHeight;
        doubleAnimation.To = canMain.ActualHeight;
        doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_marqueeTimeInSeconds));
        tbmarquee.BeginAnimation(Canvas.TopProperty, doubleAnimation);
    }

public enum MarqueeType
{
    TopToBottom
}
```

On the main window I set the xaml `MarqueeContent="Live Feed"` like so but how can I set the content in the code behind and how can I set multiple MarqueeContents?

For instance even if I was able to set the MarqueeContent from code behind and I added multiple items to it, it will no doubt just add it one after the other like the text your reading just now, I need it so each item I add has at least a paragraph spacing if that makes sense.

To give a visual idea on it you can see it here (TopDown):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48267/Making-a-Simple-Marquee-Text-Control-Drip-Animatio

I need it so I can load multiple strings into it. And that each string of text added is separated by a paragraph.

Comment: But you don't want those items to be animated independently, just have one moving block of text with paragraph spacing between the lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is only about adding multiple lines of text to one moving block, you could simply add line breaks between the lines:

```
textBlock.Text = "A line of text.\n\nAnother line of text.";
```

Or you can do the same with [Inlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines.aspx):

```
textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("A line of text."));
textBlock.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
textBlock.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("Another line of text."));
```